# Why the client does not have permission to join group in Azure Web PubSub?

Tags: azure, publish-subscribe, azure-web-pubsub, azure-pubsub

Dear AzureWebPubSub users, I was following this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/webpubsub/dataplane/web-pub-sub/generate-client-token?view=rest-webpubsub-dataplane-2023-07-01&tabs=HTTP) to fetch the client access token for Azure WebPubSub and it returned me a JWT token and on decoding it was:-

```
{
  "alg": "HS256",
  "kid": "s-5acf1aac-944d-43a6-b107-dcb529eb11fb",
  "typ": "JWT"
}.{
  "sub": "5753",
  "nbf": 1707417893,
  "exp": 1707421493,
  "iat": 1707417893,
  "iss": "https://webpubsub.azure.com",
  "aud": "https://<my-pubsub-instance>.webpubsub.azure.com/client/hubs/<hub_name>"
}
```

I sent POST request, the URL was:-

```
https://<my-pubsub-instance>.webpubsub.azure.com/api/hubs/<hub_name>/:generateToken?userId=5753&roles=webpubsub.joinLeaveGroup&api-version=2021-10-01
```

But when my client connects with the Azure WebPubSub Service, the following are the messages/logs received on the live trace tool

- Request started.
- Connection started
- Received a message [260303712814104577] from client connection SCBwg74LmXFrl8tE-3xXqgmSET3gK02.
- **Failed to send message** [260303712814104577]: **The client does not have permission to join group 'Organization_1108'**..

Quoting from this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-web-pubsub/concept-client-protocols#1-assign-the-role-to-the-client-when-generating-the-access-token):-

> Client can connect to the service using a JWT token, the token payload
> can carry information such as the role of the client. When signing the
> JWT token to the client, you can grant permissions to the client by
> giving the client specific roles.

**But when decoded the JWT token returned, it didn't carry any role information.**(Can be seen above in decoded token)

Could anyone please help me in resolving this issue? What wrong I am doing while generating the access token for the client?

Comment: Could you include what RBAC role you currently have or granted to service principal under Azure Web PubSub service?

Comment: @Sridevi, I have granted **Web PubSub Service Owner** role to Service Principal

Answer (score 0):

By adding the role **Web PubSub Service Owner**, the user can join groups in Azure Web PubSub.

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: appId
client_secret: secret 
resource: https://webpubsub.azure.com
```

[image]

```http
https://<my-pubsub-instance>.webpubsub.azure.com/api/hubs/<hub_name>/:generateToken?userId=5753&roles=webpubsub.joinLeaveGroup&api-version=2021-10-01
```

[image]

-The below WebSocket client code for Azure Web PubSub has permissions to join or leave any group and publish messages to any group.

```js
const WebSocket = require('ws');


// Replace these placeholders with your actual values
const WEBSOCKET_ENDPOINT = 'wss://test.webpubsub.azure.com/client';
const HUB_NAME = 'your_hub_name';
const ACCESS_TOKEN = 'your_access_token';


// Create WebSocket connection
const webSocket = new WebSocket(`${WEBSOCKET_ENDPOINT}/hubs/${HUB_NAME}?access_token=${ACCESS_TOKEN}`);


// Connection opened
webSocket.on('open', function (event) {
    console.log('WebSocket connection opened');
    
    // Example: join a specific group
    joinGroup('group1');
    
    // Example: send a message to a specific group
    sendMessageToGroup('group2', { message: 'Hello from the client!' });
});


// Listen for messages
webSocket.on('message', function (data) {
    console.log('Message from server:', data);
});


// Join a group
function joinGroup(groupName) {
    const joinGroupMessage = {
        type: 'joinGroup',
        group: groupName,
        ackId: Date.now(), // You can use any unique identifier here
    };
    webSocket.send(JSON.stringify(joinGroupMessage));
}


// Leave a group
function leaveGroup(groupName) {
    const leaveGroupMessage = {
        type: 'leaveGroup',
        group: groupName,
        ackId: Date.now(), // You can use any unique identifier here
    };
    webSocket.send(JSON.stringify(leaveGroupMessage));
}


// Send a message to a group
function sendMessageToGroup(groupName, message) {
    console.log('Sending message to group:', groupName);
    console.log('Message:', message);


    const sendMessageToGroupMessage = {
        type: 'sendToGroup',
        group: groupName,
        ackId: Date.now(), // You can use any unique identifier here
        dataType: 'json',
        data: message,
    };
    webSocket.send(JSON.stringify(sendMessageToGroupMessage));
}
```

**Output:**
[image]